# Change of state of a button when editing a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtextpane

I would to know how to apply a listener about a JtextPane, because I would to disable a button when the JTextPane is empty and activate a button when there are somethings in it. 
I've tried with an ItemChangeListener but it doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html), by the link there's a tutorial to help you solve your task.

Comment: you are welcome :) Please accept the answer (with green mark) to let others find solution easily.